# Test dependency/correlation between genetic sketch and description sketch

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, independence, canonical-correlation

How can I test is there a dependency/correlation between genetic sketch and description sketch ? Lets say I've got data like this:

```
genetic<-data.frame(Eye=c("Brown","Blue","Green"),
                    Hair=c("Black","Blond","Blond"),
                    Age=c("20-30","40-50","20-30"),
                    Sex=c("Male","Male","Female"))

description<-data.frame(Eye=c("Brown","Blue","Blue"),
                        Hair=c("Brown","Blond","Blond"),
                        Age=c("20-30","20-30","30-40"),
                        Sex=c("Male","Male","Female"))

> genetic
    Eye  Hair   Age    Sex
1 Brown Black 20-30   Male
2  Blue Blond 40-50   Male
3 Green Blond 20-30 Female
> description
    Eye  Hair   Age    Sex
1 Brown Brown 20-30   Male
2  Blue Blond 20-30   Male
3  Blue Blond 30-40 Female
```

where row `i`  in each dataset corresponds to the same person, this is:

Genetic test for person 1 sad he was male with brown eyes, black hair between 20 and 30 years. another person described him as a male with brown eyes, brown hair between 20 and 30 years. Etc.

I was thinking about canonical correlation but I'm not sure is this solution correct in this situation. Any help will be appreciated